# Can I say instead of "the city of Phoenix": "the capital city of Phoenix","the state's capital city of Phoenix"or "Arizona's capital city of Phoenix"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know "the city of Phoenix" is a correct phrase. But I'm curious about whether we can expand it or not. For example:
**(1)** *This is the capital city of Phoenix.*
**(2)** *This is the state's capital city of Phoenix.*
**(3)** *This is Arizona's capital city of Phoenix.*

Which of them are correct and which are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all three of your suggestions the grammar allows for them be misunderstood as saying that "this" refers to the capital city of something called "Phoenix". A similar construction would be the following remark made by a person standing in St Petersburg, "This was the Tsar's capital city of Russia".

The form "capital city of xxx" is common and well understood; if xxx is Arizona it refers to Phoenix. Likewise the form "city of xxxx" is common and well understood; it refers to the city named xxx. The first form will not easily be understood to mean what you want; the hearer/reader needs to know something about the relationship between states and capital cities to make sense of the sentences.

The phrase "city of Phoenix" can be thought of as a unit, but putting "capital" in front breaks the unit by forming a different unit "capital city". If you want to keep the unit you need to separate "capital" from "city" somehow. Here are some suggestions.

> This is the capital, the city of Phoenix.
>
> This is the state's capital, the city of Phoenix.
>
> This is Arizona's capital, the city of Phoenix.

Alternatively you could break the unit "city of Phoenix" thus:

> This is the capital city, Phoenix.
>
> This is the state's capital city, Phoenix.
>
> This is Arizona's capital city, Phoenix.

Comment: "_The capital city of Phoenix_" can be misunderstood: the capital city of something called "Phoenix". But "_the state's capital city of Phoenix_" and "_Arizona's capital city of Phoenix_" can't be misunderstood this way because they have "_the state's_" and "_Arizona's_" at the beginning. Are they still unnatural too? Thanks.

Comment: Canberra is Walter Burley Griffin's capital city of Australia. Canberra is the name of the city, Australia is the country it is the capital of, and Walter Burley Griffin was the architect who designed the city. I have edited my answer to try to make the problem clearer.

Comment: "_Canberra is Walter Burley Griffin's capital city of Australia_." = "_Canberra is the capital city of Australia **designed by** Walter Burley Griffin_." — As I understood the apostrophe after "Walter Burley Griffin" means "designed by". "_St Petersburg was the Tsar's capital city of Russia_." = "_St Petersburg was the capital city of Russia **X** the Tsar_." — But I can't understand what X means here. Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: The apostrophe is sometimes called "possessive", but it doesn't necessarily refer to ownership. It is often a different type of link, as you pointed out with Canberra. The ***X*** could be replaced by *under* or *when ruled by* - the link was the Tsar's position as ruler of Russia.

Comment: You wrote about the sentences in the original question that: "_The first form will not easily be understood to mean what you want; the hearer/reader needs to know something about the relationship between states and capital cities to make sense of the sentences._" — Does it mean that if the hearer/reader knows about the relationship discussed, then in this case these sentences sound correct to him?

Comment: No, it means that it will sound wrong but the hearer/reader will be able to work out what is meant.